# Ruby while loop not stopping when condition is met

Tags: ruby, loops, while-loop

I starting to learn Ruby, and i'm stuck with this program i'm writing which is suppose to be the game "Craps" small part of the game at least anyway, the code is looping at the 2nd while loop even when the random dice is meeting the loop's condition.

This is the loop that keeps looping

```
while new_dice_sum != 7 or new_dice_sum != 11 or new_dice_sum != 2 or new_dice_sum != 3 or new_dice_sum != 12 or new_dice_sum != point
                    dice1 = 1 + rand(6)
                    dice2 = 1 + rand(6)
                    new_dice_sum = dice1.to_i + dice2.to_i
```

This is the complete code of the program.

```
input = ""
point = 0
balance = 100
Bet = 10
dice1 = 0
dice2 = 0
dice_sum = 0
new_dice_sum = 0
won = 0
lost = 0
while input != "Q"
    print "Please choose R to roll the dice or Q to exit the game: "
    input = gets.chomp.upcase
    if input == "R"
        if balance > 10
            dice1 = 1 + rand(6)
            dice2 = 1 + rand(6)
            dice_sum = dice1.to_i + dice2.to_i
            puts "First dice is #{dice1} while the second dice is #{dice2} both are a total of #{dice_sum}"
            if dice_sum == 7 || dice_sum == 11
                balance = balance + Bet
                won = won + 1
                puts "You won, Your new balance is #{balance}"
            elsif dice_sum == 2 || dice_sum == 3 || dice_sum == 12
                balance = balance - Bet
                lost = lost + 1
                puts "You lost, Your new balance is #{balance}"
            else
                point = dice_sum
                while new_dice_sum != 7 or new_dice_sum != 11 or new_dice_sum != 2 or new_dice_sum != 3 or new_dice_sum != 12 or new_dice_sum != point
                    dice1 = 1 + rand(6)
                    dice2 = 1 + rand(6)
                    new_dice_sum = dice1.to_i + dice2.to_i
                    puts "In the new roll with your point #{point}, The first dice is #{dice1} while the second dice is #{dice2} both are a total of #{new_dice_sum}"
                    if new_dice_sum == 7 || new_dice_sum == 11
                        balance = balance + Bet
                        won = won + 1
                        puts "You won, Your new balance is #{balance}"
                    elsif new_dice_sum == 2 || new_dice_sum == 3 || new_dice_sum == 12
                        balance = balance - Bet
                        lost = lost + 1
                        puts "You lost, Your new balance is #{balance}"
                    elsif new_dice_sum == point 
                        balance = balance + Bet
                        won = won + 1 
                        puts "Your Total dice is equal to your point you won, your new balance is #{balance}"
                    end
                end
            end  
        else
            puts "Your balance is not enough to place a bet, Your balance now is #{balance}"
        end
    elsif input != "Q"
    puts "#{input} is not valid choice"
    end
end
puts "Your current balance is #{balance}$ and you won #{won} times and lost #{lost} times"
exit
```

Comment: If you want to stop the loop, you should call return. And also your code is to complicated using nested if and loops.

Comment: If you have your answer i Suggest closing the post or marking an answer accepted. Not everybody reads the comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are doing **or** on all of the parameters, so even if it matches first it will pass not matching the second.

Change your logic for while loop from `variable != firstcondition or variable != secondcondition` ...
to 
`!(variable == condition or variable == condition ... )`

Comment: Uh... you probably want `==` in there, not `=`. Personally, I'd just suggest `while ![7,11,2,3,12].include?(variable)`

Comment: lol yes, ty, updated the answer, wasn't sure on ruby syntax was looking at logic

Comment: i was under the impression that if any of the **or** return true the loop will end.

Comment: no, if any of the **or** yields TRUTH it will enter the loop, For example if the new_dice_sum is 7, then the first check yields FALSE but **or** means keep checking, and the next statement (7 != 11) is not TRUE

Comment: @sary no, if any of the disjuncts in the chain of `or`s return true, then the whole chain is true and so the loop _continues_. Only if _all_ of the disjuncts are false does the loop end.

Comment: I mean second statement would be TRUE :)

Comment: `while num > 1 or num <= 1:` is ALWATS true

Comment: Yes @danchik you are correct. Now I get it, I was confused and using the logic of == and not !=